# passing the product of two floating point numbers to a macro

Tags: macros, pgfmath, floating-point

I have a macro

```
\mywonderfulmacro{...}
```

that expects an ordinary floating point number in lieu of `...`. (For example,

```
\mywonderfulmacro{4.51}
```

is valid.) Now I would like to do something like this:

```
\def\a{1.2}
\def\b{1.3}
\mywondefulmacro{\a * \b}
```

The hope would of course be that the above code results in

```
\mywonderfulmacro{1.56}
```

being evaluated. Unfortunately, TeX doesn't work this way and I get an error!

What is the correct/easiest way to do this?

PS: I know the answer is surely implicit in previous questions/answers to this forum, given sufficient discernment, but my know-how is very low so please I please need an answer that addresses this specific question in this specific situation, not a pointer to some technical post with `\the` `\numexpr` and whatnot :/

Comment: Now is this about `TeX` ... or is LaTeX also possible? `\the\numexpr\a*\b` wouldn't work for floating point content anyway

Answer (score 1):

The `xfp` package provides the access to `expl3` `fp` floating point 'library' and the macro `\fpeval` is meant for such calculations. It is expandable.

`\numexpr\anumber*\bnumber` won't work, by the way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\def\anumber{1.2}
\def\bnumber{1.3}

\newcommand{\mywonderfulmacro}[1]{\fpeval{#1}}

\begin{document}


\mywonderfulmacro{\anumber * \bnumber}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\theproduct}{\a*\b}
\mywonderfulmacro{\theproduct}
```

will work.

Any other solutions/insights appreciated!

Comment: note that xfp in the other answer is expandable (and more accurate in general)